# Is it possible to use OpenCV to accurately detect water in a sewage pipe?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-recognition

I'm looking into image-recognition of water in sewage pipes for a future project.

I have been looking into OpenCV, and it looks like it is very good at recognizing where objects start, and stop. However, is there anything in OpenCV that would not only allow for separating water from pipe, but also identifying which is which?

Edit: Here is an example of the image type (taken from video):
http://imageshack.us/f/851/vlcsnap2011061516h22m54.png/

Comment: Please add an example image. It is very difficult to advise how to solve image processing problems without any example images.

Comment: Added an example image, as requested.

Comment: Hmm - looks like we need a `sewage` tag...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say you have video that may help you define what is "water" and what is "pipe".
The "pipe" is the part of the image stream that doesn't move (as seen from a fixed camera), while the "water" part is the one with larger differences in successive frames (due to illumination and flow).

BTW, must your sensor really be optical? Since you are already introducing a relatively expensive sensor in the system, can't you use a specialized sensor that detects what you're really after?

Comment: Agreed, see what other industrial sensors you can use. However, the security- / IP- / web-cam quality in the example image isn't exactly evidence of an expensive sensors. CMOS is incredibly cheap for the amount of data you get.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental problems you will face won't be with the software. OpenCV has plenty of capacity for what you are attempting to do. The real engineering you need to tackle will be optical. You need to ensure a proper field of view and illumination.

There are integrators that can bring together the image processing software and optical engineering using most whatever software platform you require. http://www.machinevisiononline.org/ is a decent resource

Comment: Are there any existing software projects that deal with a similar problem (using OpenCV)? Edit: Also, just to clarify, the image source will be from all different types of hardware, so I have no real guarantee, or control, over the quality of the incoming images.

Comment: @David there are a whole set of libraries similar to opencv - the main commercial one is probably MIL (matrox imaging library). The difficulty is knowing what you are looking for  what does water 'look like' - rather than the detaisl of the library

Comment: +1 question should be rephrased as "can vision algorithms detect water in pipe?"

Comment: Matlab and LabVIEW also have perfectly capable imaging library add-ons. However you have to know which tools from the box to use. There are many possibilities: background subtraction, edge detection, pattern recognition, optical flow measurement, etc. 

My advice would be to prototype two or three of these methods using the tool you choose. You will get a feel for what illumination + scene conditions they are applicable for. Then you can combine the various methods using weighting or voting algorithms. Be emperical about it- the human visual cortex is amazing- software will never match it.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to look at the texture.
On the example image it seems as the water surface is more smooth than the visible parts of the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

A water level sensor not only tells you if there is water but also gives you the depth.  Knowing the depth and pipe diameter allows you to compute the volume of water going through the pipe.  See

http://www.instrumart.com/products/25311/flowline-echosonic-ii-ultrasonic-level-transmitter